# Packing squares into a circle

Tags: circles, packing-problem

I need determine the maximum number of squares  of the given size that can be packed into a circle of the given radius. Squares can  be rotated. I'm not sure how complex this problem is and i can find little about it on the other sites.

Comment: This sounds like a hard problem. But while I understand the need to pack circular/spherical things (e.g. oranges) into square things (e.g. boxes), why would one want to pack square things in a circle??

Comment: @TMM: I think that there is a thin connection with getting as many silicon wafers (squares?) as possible out of a circular piece.

Comment: see Open Access paper published: 03 October 2018 : [**Rigorous packing of unit squares into a circle**, T Montanher et al, Journal of Global Optimization volume 73, pages547–565(2019)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10898-018-0711-5)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a hard case-by-case problem.  [This beautiful page](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/squincir/) shows the records for the smallest circle packed with $n$ unit squares for $n$ from 1 to 35.  You can see that there's nothing obvious about most of the solutions.  Of course, as you pack more and more squares into a circle, there's less and less to be gained by finding a clever arrangement.